# how to convert raw utf8mb4_unicode_ci like X'313735313136' to a regular string (utf8) in php

Tags: php, sql, string, utf-8, utf8mb4

This question is about converting a raw utf8mb4_unicode_ci from a .sql to a normal utf-8

My .sql was from a database that had COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

like this :

```
(5558,'2019-11-18 18:28:36',X'313735313136','am',''),
```

in PHP how would I convert this `X'313735313136'` to a normal utf8 string ?

I tried `utf8_decode("\xE18885E18C8D");` but the result is `?8885E18C8D` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the collation of the database, the exported file you are looking at has decoded that and has provided a binhex encoding. I'm not sure what a reasonable value is for that column, but

```
php -r "print hex2bin('313735313136');"
```

returns `175116`

Comment: thanks ;) it returns what I expected : ህግ